# Exclude Specifically Tagged tests from SBT when using ScalaTest

Tags: scala, sbt, automated-tests, scalatest

I'm having a lot of frustration trying to run all my tests from `sbt`- while excluding a specific tag. Here is what I am trying to run:

```
testOnly * -- -l "com.my.project.path.tags.ValidationTest"
```

I've tried many variations of this command, including replacing the `*` with the path to a class or the path to a package like so:

```
testOnly "com.my.project.path.somePackage" -- -l "com.my.project.path.tags.ValidationTest"
```

And I've tried with and without quotes around the package.

I just read that `testOnly` is used in the new version of `sbt` and not `test-only`. I've tried this syntax (and many variations), and nothing seems to work.
I have my tests set up like this:

```
"some method" should "fail when doing something" taggedAs ValidationTest in { ... }
```

I have `object ValidationTest extends Tag("com.my.project.path.tags.ValidationTest")` defined in `TestTag.scala`.

I have also attempted this when the method is defined with the `it` keyword, instead of `"some method" should "fail..."`

[Sbt with ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt) shows the following under "*Include and Exclude Tests with Tags*"

```
> test-only org.acme.* -- -n CheckinTests
> test-only org.acme.* -- -n FunctionalTests -l org.scalatest.tags.Slow
> test-only org.acme.* -- -n "CheckinTests FunctionalTests" -l "org.scalatest.tags.Slow org.scalatest.tags.Network"
```

Comment: To be clear, you do or do not want those tags to run? Sounds like you do not want things with that tag to run, which I don't believe ScalaTest supports.

Comment: ScalaTest absolutely **does** support skipping these tags, or including them via the `-n` or `-l` flags. See here: [ScalaTest with Sbt](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_sbt). See 3/4 down on the page.

Comment: I know it is an old post, but I tried to reproduce your issue, and I can't reproduce it. Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Manually exclude some test classes in sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29163221/2359227)

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of guesses:

- all this syntax works only from sbt console and DOES NOT work from command line;
- the package name should be WITHOUT quotes and should end with asterix, the tag should be WITH quotes (e.g. `testOnly com.my.project.* -- -l "com.my.project.path.tags.ValidationTest"`)
- testOnly concerns only unit tests, if you should have integration tests, you should use e.g. `it:testOnly * -- -l "path.to.Tag"`.

Comment: I haven't tested this - but yes I think it has to do with me not using the sbt console - and also not using quotes

Comment: So how can I do any of the same things from the command line?

Comment: One thing to try out would be passing commands as parameters to sbt console e.g. in a batch file/shell script. I haven't tried it yet tho and do not know if it is at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

To run all test apart from tests with a specific tag:

```
sbt "testOnly -- -l com.my.project.path.tags.ValidationTest"
```

To then do the opposite, only tests with a tag:

```
sbt "testOnly -- -n com.my.project.path.tags.ValidationTest"
```